# Is there an function or algorithm to get outermost surface by using information of node & element connectivity?

Tags: game-physics, convex-hull, physics-engine, convex-polygon

Is there an function or algorithm to get outermost surface by using information of node & element connectivity?
Since the general convex hull algorithm uses only node information, only the triangular surface can be obtained by searching the outermost surface.
I want to get surface information by using element connectivity.